# if quadratic $x^2-(a+b+c)x+ab+bc+ca=0$ has complex roots, Then prove that $\sqrt{a}$,$\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ are sides of triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratics

> The following quadratic equation $$x^2-(a+b+c)x+ab+bc+ca=0$$ has complex roots.
>
> Prove that $\sqrt{a}$,$\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ are sides-lengths of triangle, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

Since the quadratic has complex roots, we have Discriminant negative. So

$$(a+b+c)^2 \lt 4ab+4bc+4ca$$ $\implies$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \lt 2(ab+bc+ca)$$ $\implies$

$$c^2-2c(a+b)+(a-b)^2 \lt 0$$ $\implies$

$$(a+c-b)^2 \lt 4ac$$ $\implies$

we get

$$a+c-b \lt 2 \sqrt{ac}$$

any clue further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the given we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)>0$$ or
$$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})\prod_{cyc}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})>0$$
because 
\begin{align}
\sum_{cyc}(2ab-a^2)&=4ab-(a+b-c)^2\\
&=\left(2\sqrt{ab}\right)^2-(a+b-c)^2\\
&=(2\sqrt{ab}-a-b+c)(2\sqrt{ab}+a+b-c)\\
&=(c-(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2)((\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2-c)\\
&=(\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}).
\end{align}
Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Hence, $\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{a}>0$ and rest multipliers are also positives.

Done!

Comment: Typo in line 8: $+-$ should be just $+$. Also, do you need quite so many equality signs?

Comment: @John Bentin I fixed. Thank you! We have no any equality because for example $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{b}>0$ automatically.

Comment: I've reformatted to make it somewhat more readable.

Comment: @John Hughes Thank you!

Comment: The redundant equality signs were removed in John Hughes' reformatting.

Comment: You're welcome. "begin/end{align}" is a great way to make your displayed equations more readable.

Comment: @John Bentin If  John Hughes wants to write it in this form and it will do him good then will do. In my opinion, we need to write $=$ in  both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Continuing from where you left off, we can write your last inequality as $$(\surd c)^2-(\surd a-\surd b)^2>0.$$When we factorize this difference of squares, we see that $\surd c+\surd a-\surd b$ and $\surd c-\surd a+\surd b$ are either both positive or both negative. The latter can be ruled out, since their sum $2\surd c$ is positive. Hence $\surd c+\surd a>\surd b$ and $\surd c+\surd b>\surd a$. By the symmetry of the original data, $\surd a+\surd b>\surd c$ too.